# Calling a method from a class that is a subclass of a class of which i have made an ArrayList of

Tags: java, arraylist

I had attached the code in the end.

So i have a class called Product, ComputerPart and Ram. Ram extends Computer part , ComputerPart  extends product from which all classes override price attribute since Product is an abstract class.

Is my implementation of an ArrayList vs a List correct ? 
How do i reach a getter method in the ComputerParts class via the arraylist. 
I am a little confused on when i pass 76f though ComputerPart , how is it usable since it has not been properly instanciated

```
abstract class Product {
    protected float price;
    public static int i =0;                   // to keep count starts at zero 
    protected static int ID ;               // to update and keep track of ID even if i changes 

     // return the price of a particular product
    abstract float price();
}


class ComputerPart extends Product {

     public ComputerPart(float p) {
        i += 1;                             // each time constructor invoked ,  
        ID = i ;                                // to update ID even if i changes.    
        price = p;
    }

    public float price() { return price; }

    public static String getID(){   // a getter method so ID can be nicely formated and returned
        String Identification =  "ID#" + ID;
        return Identification;
    }
}

public abstract class GenericOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Product> genericOrder= new ArrayList<Product>();
        genericOrder.add(new ComputerPart(76f));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.... what problem do you have? You should know that a subclass instance **is a** super class instance too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ArrayList vs List. Could you explain in more detail what you're worried about?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Product> genericOrder= new ArrayList<Product>();
```

This is fine, though it is better practice to declare the variable type as the List interface (which makes your code more modular, since you can easily switch to a different List implementation) :

```
List<Product> genericOrder= new ArrayList<Product>();
```

As for accessing specific properties of the objects stored in the list :

You can fetch the Product from the list :

```
Product p = genericOrder.get(0);
```

Then you can check if it's a `ComputerPart` and cast it in order to access the specific methods of `ComputerPart` :

```
if (p instanceof ComputerPart) {
    ComputerPart c = (ComputerPart) p;
    System.out.prinln(c.price());
}
```

Comment: I don't think the casting is necessary. The goal to make `List<Product>` instead of `List<ComputerPart>` is to abstract the `price()` method. so just `genericOrder.get(0).price()`

Comment: @Kent That may be true for the price() property, which might make sense to be in the base class, but in general, the sub-class can have specific properties that the base class doesn't have, and casting is the only way to access them.

Comment: Thank you everyone. 
Yes i do understand now. 
@Kent when i try to do it your way by trying to access getID()method it says its undefined for product 

 i understand your explanation. I am still a bit confused how that if statement is working on getting me to the getID() method inside ComputerPart class